# List of objects obtaining information

Tags: c#, list

I am still having issues getting my data out of a list.  My list contains a list of objects. (if that makes sense)

I think it's just a syntax issue.  but I need to get to the object level to call the properties.

so here is the structure of my list when I go to thought the debugger to give you an idea how deep it is.

    `Name           Value`

> ItemList    count = 40
>         -> [0]       count = 1
>             --->[0]     {namespace.class}
>   ----> Propties      Values
>    
>   Now at this point I can see the properties and the values to these properties.

What is the syntax to access these properties?

I will describe how my structure is setup.  So here is my list of my "Component objects"

```
List<Component> SYNCItems = new List<Component>();
```

All properties are being assigned to the objects and added into this list.

Now list SyncItems is being added to ItemsList amoung other items.

```
List<Object> ItemsList = new List<object>();

ItemsList.Add(SYNCItems);
```

So it's like a multi array list.

Does this help?

Comment: Show us some code defining your "list of objects."

Comment: `ItemList[0][0].PropName` maybe ?

Comment: Instead of showing what the debugger is showing, it would be a lot more helpful if you posted some code instead because this isn't a debugging issue.

Comment: Random objects, as in List<object> or specific? If specific, iterate through the list with a for or foreach and display the properties by name.

Comment: Can you be more specific with your code? Show an example?

Comment: There is no List in c#, do you mean List<SYNCItems>?  If that is the case, you should be able to access the properties using ItemsList[0][0].PropertyName as others pointed out.

Comment: This is your problem. `List<Object> ItemsList = new List<object>();` should be `var ItemsList = new List<List<Component>>();`. By having them stored as objects you lose the fact that they are lists.

Comment: Follow Chris's advice and do not use List<Object>

Comment: (ItemsList[0] as List<Component>)[0].PropertyName should work

Answer (score 1):

**(Edited in response to the latest information)**

You're using `List<object>` to store what should be a `List<List<Component>>`. The component list can be placed inside the object list, but it'll be stored as an object and you will no longer be able to access it as a list without casting back.

Change to the following:

```
List<Object> ItemsList = new List<object>();
```

to

```
var ItemsList = new List<List<Component>>(); // you can use type inference to save you some typing
```

(If you're using C# 2.0, specify type name instead of `var` as below:)

```
List<List<Component>> ItemsList = new List<List<Component>>();
```

You should then be able to access the inner list via `ItemList[0][0].Property` or by foreach iteration etc.

Comment: Is it a List or IEnumerable? Not all collections can be accessed by indexer syntax, though a List of Lists certainly could be.

Comment: @Andy12 I've updated my answer in response to your provided details.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read the data out, you could get the inner list.

```
var innerList = ItemList.SelectMany(i => ((List<Component>)i).ToList());
```

Then you can access the properties:

```
foreach(var prop in innerList)
      //do something with prop.myProperty
```

EDIT - Updated answer in reply to edited question. Use `List<Component>` instead of `List<object>`.

Answer (score 1):

Misread the question at first.  Assuming you mean something like:

```
List<List<Person>>;
```

Here is an example:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

List<List<Person>> superHeroes = new List<List<Person>>();
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

Person p = new Person {Name = "Superman"};
Person p2 = new Person {Name = "Batman"};
Person p3 = new Person {Name = "Spiderman"};

persons.Add(p);
persons.Add(p2);
persons.Add(p3);

superHeroes.Add(persons);

string batmanName = superHeroes[0][0].Name; //returns "Superman"
```

When you say your list contains a list of objects, do you mean a list within a list or just a list that contains more than 1 object.

Comment: He mentioned in response to my answer that the `superHeroes[0][0].Name` syntax doesn't work for him. I'm not entirely sure they're actually `List<>` types.

Comment: Yeah, if it is a List<>, your code works for me, so I  guess more details is needed.  It goes a long way in helping you efficiently and accurately.

Comment: Yes.  My list contains multiple obects

Comment: I added more to my orignal question let me know if that helps.

Comment: Based on your update, looks like you are just using generic list within a generic list.  You should be able to access the properties via the itemsList[0][0].propertyName?

Comment: @Xaisoft the question has been edited and should be solvable now.

Comment: Like Chris said, use var List<List<Component>> instead of List<Object>

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
  ItemList.ElementAt(0).ElementAt(0).Properties
```

Or something to that effect.

I think you want to access the list elements which is ElementAt(int index)

Comment: It's a list so you'd better go with `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see your issue now. Here you go. Try this:

```
        List<SomeClass> SYNCItems = new List<SomeClass>();

        var obj1 = new SomeClass() { SomeProperty = "test" };
        SYNCItems.Add(obj1);

        var obj2 = new SomeClass() { SomeProperty = "test" };
        SYNCItems.Add(obj2);

        List<Object> ItemsList = new List<object>();

        ItemsList.Add(SYNCItems);


        var list = (ItemsList[0]) as List<SomeClass>;

        Console.WriteLine(list[0].SomeProperty);
        Console.WriteLine(list[1].SomeProperty);
```

And just for completeness, here is SomeClass. :)

```
public class SomeClass
{
     public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i am using C# 2005 var doesn't seem to be reconized as a keyword.

Comment: I'm not sure he really *wants* `List<object>`, it seems to me that he just doesn't know he can have `List<List<Component>>`. I think you need to clarify this.